# CordovaLib classes missing with phonegap@3.5.0-0.2.7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

i am using **Phongap@3.5.0-0.2.7** and i am new to Phonegap.

The problem is when i create a new project using **CL** and then open it in eclipse, a red sign appears in the project that **cordovalib.jar** file is missing.

What I can do to resolving it?

**cordovalib** file looks like.

```
(app-cordovalib.jar - D:\app\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin(missing)).
```

I am stuck please help me to resolve this problem.

On cmd all commands are running correctly (project created successfully,project build successfully).

Comment: Please mention the steps you have taken?

Comment: Firsi i install nodejs
secondly i install cordova 
then create new project
then add android platform
then build the project and it successfully build
then i open project in eclipse from android existing code

Answer (score 0):

You might have imported in wrong way.

Import as:

- **File - > Import - > Android - > Existing Android Code into Workspace**
- Browse the **generated** android folder **inside** the platforms and click **Finish** (see snapshot)
- It will **import android** project along with **cordova lib**
- **Clean** the projects Or can **set** desired android version and then clean
- Run the app on simulator or device

[image]

Comment: nops i have imported in the right way same like this

Comment: then check the Android and JDK version on the project properties. Right click on the project -> properties and check both. Then clean the project

Comment: and did you see the CordovaLib project while importing it? as shown in snapshot

Comment: can you tell how to clean the project

Comment: Inside Eclipse, select Project menu -- > clean

Comment: i cant find the clean option

Comment: Update the question and include your snapshots of eclipse and error message so that better help can be provided